# Why existing function arguments cannot be used to evaluate other default arguments?

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, default-arguments

I was writing a function `foo()` which takes 2 `const char*`s as arguments, `pBegin` and `pEnd`. `foo()` is passed a null terminated string. By default `pEnd` points to `\0` (last character) of the string.

```
void foo (const char *pBegin,
          const char *pEnd = strchr(pBegin, 0))  // <--- Error
{
  ...
}
```

However, I get an error at above line as:

```
error: local variable ‘pBegin’ may not appear in this context
```

Why compiler doesn't allow such operation ? What's the potential problem ?

Comment: Different calling conventions push parameters in different orders. Some typical ones (`cdecl`, `stdcall`) push right-to-left, so in your example `pEnd` would need to be evaluated before `pBegin`, which I don't think makes sense... Have a squiz here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard not only explicitly disallows the use of other parameters in a default argument expression, but also explains why and gives an example:

> #### ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) - 8.3.6 Default arguments [dcl.fct.default]
>
> *9.* Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called.
>   **The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.
>   Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in default
>   argument expressions, even if they are not evaluated.** Parameters of a
>   function declared before a default argument expression are in scope
>   and can hide namespace and class member names. *[Example:*
>
> ```
>     int a;
>     int f(int a, int b = a);         // error: parameter a
>                                      // used as default argument
>     typedef int I;
>     int g(float I, int b = I(2));    // error: parameter I found
>     int h(int a, int b = sizeof(a)); // error, parameter a used
>                                      // in default argument
> ```
>
> *—end example]* ...

Comment: The last example may look overly strict.  We know sizeof(a) == sizeof(int) regardless of the value of a.  The argument of evaluation order doesn't apply, so this case _could_ be allowed.  But g++ 4.8.2 raises the expected error.  I guess this is in the interest of keeping the rules simple.

Comment: Agreed. Also template parameters seem to count as parameters in that sense since recent versions of g++. For example, template<class T> void g(T x=default_value<T>()) is an error. This is an annoyance.

Answer (score 6):

The language still offers a way to do what you want - use overloaded functions:

```
void foo (const char *pBegin, const char *pEnd)
{
   //...
}

void foo (const char *pBegin)
{ foo(pBegin, strchr(pBegin, 0)); }
```

Answer (score 3):

When the function is called the default arguments are evaluated, but the order they are evaluated is not defined by the C++ standard. That means that you can't reference other parameters in a default argument because they may not have a known value yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a local variable in a default argument value.

[Quote from here:](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/167487-whats-rule-default-argument-function-c)

> The standard tells us that the default argument is simply an expression.
>   There are some things that are no allowed (using local variables, using
>   the keyword 'this') but pretty much anything else can serve as a default
>   argument.